Creating a charts based on "created date" with filter of user regarding their language [looker-studio]
I need to create a Chart displaying my new user daily count with a column for each "preferred language"
So I started by creating a Chart displaying my new user count daily. This is the simple part. What bothers me is that I cannot find a way to have several columns for each language (EN, DE, FR,...)
Here is my field: "Created Date", "Preferred language = de/en/fr"
I tried to create a new field using If formula and Case but I cannot have a proper visualization and it's driving me insane.
The only way I find to do it is to create individual charts and blend them...
